# Longer Route for ActionResult Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, routes, action

Is it possible in MVC 4 to give a method a longer route than just /{controller}/{method}?

That is, how could I have a method "test", and have it's path be /{controller}/api/test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Simply define the api/test route before the general `/{controller}/{method}` so that the api/test route kicks in before the general route.

NOTE: When you define the /api/test, you'll need to specify the default action method.

Also, are you using WebAPI?

Comment: There are other methods in the same controller that need to still call from the root {controller}/{method} level. Would that mess it up? Also, yeah, I can use WebAPI, but I'm not well acquainted with it.

Comment: That would still work. Two different routes can call action methods in the same controller.

Comment: Alright, I think I'm getting it. I've set a route for /api/{controller}/{action}/{id}, but I'm getting "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Listing'." when I try to access it.

Comment: Do you have a public `ListingController` class that inherits from 'Controller'?

Comment: Yes, although it's in a subdirectory. I don't think that should matter though.

Comment: Oh wait, I figured it out. I put the route in the wrong routing file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can register additional routes by modifying "RegisterRoutes()" in your project's Global.asax.cs file.

For example:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
 routes.MapRoute(
  "YourNewRoute",                                        // Route name
  "{controller}/api/{action}",                           // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "YourController", action = "Test" } // Parameter defaults
 );
}
```

Now, if you enter:

> YourController/api/Test

(Note the presence of "api" in the path)

it will call:

> controller = YourController
>
> action = Test

You can find more information about routes in this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs).